# AWS Athena query error: Hive File Not Found:partition location does not exist

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-glue, amazon-athena

I created one table in glue database using crawler job. Table created successfully.

However, when I am trying to access that table in athena query editor its giving me below error when i am try to select the data from table:

Query:
select * from DB1.data_tbl;

Output:
Hive File Not Found: Partition location does not exist

I haven't found the partition location define.

Please assist.

Comment: What is the table definition?

Comment: I read this table from postgres DB :              column_name  data_type
addeess1             string
checkin_time    timestamp
address    string
current_date    date
salary    decimal(15,2)
currency_type    string
emp_nm    string

Comment: Athena can't read directly PostgreSQL, unless you setup connectors. Its not clear what do you want to do. Please clarify. Did you setup a connector?

Comment: I setup connection and read the data from postgress on prem DB and crawler ran successfully and created the table.But when i tried to run the select on this table in athena query editor getting below error: Hive File Not Found: partition location does not exist

Answer (score 1):

Athena, by default, can read only data in S3. It will not read your postgresql databases. To connect to anything other than S3, you have to setup and use [Amazon Athena Federated Query](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/connect-to-a-data-source.html).

Alternatively, setup a Glue Job to copy all data from your Postegresql into S3, and then use Athena to query the data from S3.

Comment: Table Listed in Glue catalog database.But when i am trying to access that table from Athena that table not listed there and even not able to query.Getting that error.

Comment: @user2862073 I will write it again "can read only data in S3.".

Comment: can i read this table as datasource and write to s3.I tried to create a new crawler job but not able to select this table as datasource(created in glue database).